# First steps in the first convergents of the continuous fraction associated with $\Phi$

Tags: calculus

List the first six terms of the following sequences:

$$ t_1= 1, t_n= 1/(1+ t_{n-1}), \ (n \geq 2)$$

The answer key said 1, 1/2, 2/3, 3/5, 5/8, 8/13. I dont understand how to get these answers because if you start at 2 since n>= 2 wouldnt it be 1/1+1 so 1/2?? Not 1 as the answer says??

Comment: Welcome to MSE Cassandra! Are there parentheses? $1/(1+1)$ is very different from $1/1 + 1$, as those viral posts on social media love to make light of.

Comment: Its 1/(1+ tn-1)

Comment: The sequence is $t_1=1$ and if $n\ge2$ then $t_n=1/(1+t_{n-1})$. This explains the answer in the answer key.

Comment: "if you start at 2" but you don't; when it says the *first* six terms, that means you start at the first term, which is $t_1$, which is $1$.

Comment: Earlier version of this question (now closed), https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3555416/infinite-sequences-help-calculus

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: No, my question still hasnt been answered. Could someone explain how to get t1 & t2 step by step

Comment: You get $t_1$ for free because the problem told you what $t_1$ is.  The problem told you that $t_1$ is equal to $1$.  Period.  No more thought necessary.  No formula needed.  No additional steps required.  Next... now that you *already have* $t_1$, which again was told to you in the problem statement, you can now intuit what the value of $t_2$ is using the fact that you know that $t_2 = \dfrac{1}{1+t_1}$.  Since you know what $t_1$ is you can replace it in the expression and find that $t_2 = \dfrac{1}{1+1}=\dfrac{1}{2}$.  Now armed with the knowledge of of $t_2$ you can find $t_3$ etc...

Comment: As best as I can tell, you are confused as to which terms are the "*first six terms.*"  Well.. the first term is $t_1$.  The second term is $t_2$.  The third term is $t_3$ and so on with the sixth term being $t_6$.  The "*first six terms*" where you start counting from one.  It was not implied that it was talking about the first six terms *starting counting from two and on*.  If it wanted that it would have said that.  (*Admittedly, there are some contexts where the first however many terms should start counting from zero which confuses matters, but we can assume that is not the case here*)

Comment: Thank you i understand now (:

Answer (score 0):

You can start by finding $t_2$ like this:

$$t_2=\frac{1}{1+t_1}$$
$$t_2=\frac{1}{1+1}$$
$$t_2=\frac{1}{2}$$

Then plug that in to the formula again to get $t_3$

$$t_3=\frac{1}{1+t_2}$$
$$t_3=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$t_3=\frac{2}{3}$$

Then again for $t_4$

$$t_4=\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{3}}$$
$$t_4=\frac{3}{5}$$

Then $t_5$

$$t_5=\frac{1}{1+\frac{3}{5}}$$
$$t_5=\frac{5}{8}$$

Finally $t_6$

$$t_6=\frac{1}{1+\frac{5}{8}}$$
$$t_6=\frac{8}{13}$$

This gives us the same sequence as the answer key gave

$$t_1=1,t_2=\frac{1}{2},t_3=\frac{2}{3},t_4=\frac{3}{5},t_5=\frac{5}{8},t_6=\frac{8}{13}$$

As a side note, I’d avoid referring to this as an infinite series question, as there is nothing involving infinity here.

Comment: @JeanMarie I did notice that, and, considering that and the evaluation of the infinite fraction $$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\ddots}}} = {\phi}-1$$, there may be a another way to prove the often sited fact that ratios of the Fibonacci sequence converge to $\phi$

Comment: I have taken the liberty to provide your question a better title. I wish you don't object ; besides see the very good site : http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/cfINTRO.html#section1